# Android Studio. Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1. Блокировка гугл ip?

Tags: android, android-gradle

Всем привет. Сегодня 23 апреля 2018, пытаюсь скомпилировать проект в **Android Studio 3.1.1**.

Выбрал `release` сборку. Скомпилировал, компилируется без ошибок. И пытаюсь сделать билд (`Build APK(s)`).

Вылетает ошибка.

```
Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Users/mm/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
file:/Users/mm/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
file:/Users/mm/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
file:/Users/mm/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
file:/Users/mm/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom
file:/Users/mm/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.pom 
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.1/lint-gradle-26.1.1.jar
Required by:
project :app
```

В западном сегменте stack overflow пишут добавить google() в build.gradle

Мой build.gradle выглядит так

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

У меня это было добавлено. Я так понимаю не получается обратиться к этому репозиторию. Из-за блокировки части IP Google в России. Кто может помочь? Кто то сталкивался? Разработчики, у кого то уже были проблемы связанные с блокировкой IP-адресов Google?

**Решение**

Нужно было добавить cюда

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите полностью стактрейс гредла.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/uNfgcBKp3UgXpE
https://yadi.sk/d/JLZHkSs83UgXrq

два build.gradle файла

https://yadi.sk/i/DrmkwlQV3UgYH5

полный текст ошибки 

gradle версии 4.4

Comment: Добавьте в пост. Никто не станет бегать по ссылкам, скачивать себе на устройство и разбираться. И другим людям не получится аналогичную ошибку через гугл найти.

Comment: ок. сейчас сделаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы всё-таки не указали нужный репозиторий в `build.gradle` на уровне проекта. Ибо прикреплённый вами стактрейс об этом и говорит (что во всех доступных местах нужная зависимость не была найдена). В случае недоступности репозитория, ошибка была бы соответствующая, со ссылкой на «плохой» url. Проверил у себя, проблем при сборке не возникало.

Comment: Вы правы.  Добавил в 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Все заработало.